# Sub domains in nodejs

Tags: node.js, subdomain

How can I handle subdomains request by nodejs?

for example the following code echo **test** in console for any request on **http://localhost:9876/[anything]** :

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    console.log("test");
}).listen(9876);
```

now I wanna answer any request on **http://[anything].localhost:9876/[anything]**
it can be done by  **htaccess** in apache,what is alternative in NodeJS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your application is already capable of handling requests for multiple hosts.

Since you haven't specified a [`hostname`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback):

> [...] the server will accept connections directed to any IPv4 address (`INADDR_ANY`).

And, you can determine which `host` was used to make the request from the [`headers`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_headers):

```
var host = req.headers.host; // "sub.domain:9876", etc.
```

Though, you'll also need to configured an IP address for the subdomains in DNS or [`hosts`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)).

Or, with a services such as [xip.io](http://xip.io/) -- using an IP address rather than `localhost`:

```
http://127.0.0.1.xip.io:9876/
http://foo.127.0.0.1.xip.io:9876/
http://anything.127.0.0.1.xip.io:9876/
```